# Why does Python 3 read a file with encoding cp1252 by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, encoding

When doing:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f)
```

I get:

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Why is it `cp1252` by default? The `test.txt` has been saved with UTF8 encoding, and the `.py` script too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from [the documentation of open](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open):

> The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever **locale.getpreferredencoding() returns**), but any text encoding supported by Python can be used. See the codecs module for the list of supported encodings.

My bolding

If you want to read as UTF-8 you just use the argument:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f)
```

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't everything be UTF8 by default now on Python 3?

Comment: They probably dont want the hassle of setting anything specific and then have everyone else that doesn't use that complain, but I dont know :)

Comment: @Basj you could use [UTF8 mode](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0540/) also see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/locale.py#L616

Comment: @SamMason Thanks for the info. I only have Python 3.6, so `python -X utf8` doesn't work currently. I'll retry when I'll have 3.7 installed. Do you confirm it works?

Comment: @Basj I use Linux, so IO is always utf-8 for me.  that said, if I set that flag, then `sys.flags.utf8_mode` does get set

Comment: Python 3.6 switched the console and filesystem encodings to UTF-8 by default in Windows. (Internally it uses the OS native UTF-16.) But changing the default I/O encoding to UTF-8 was considered too disruptive. The preferred encoding is based on the system locale, such as codepage 1252 for Western European locales. Windows 10 allows configuring the system locale to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your default system encoding this way:

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

The you can decode and encode accordingly.